# Are white helmets propaganda or legitimate?

Tags: syria

From the West/NATO point of view the white helmets are heroes who saved an astounding number of lives (100 000).
And according to them, they were bullied and bombarded by Syria/Russia forces.

But according to Russia/Syria, they are linked to terrorists and propaganda materials.

[White Helmets member caught on camera disposing of Syrian soldiers’ mutilated bodies](https://www.rt.com/news/393809-white-helmets-mutilated-bodies/)

['Massive evidence foreign-funded White Helmets support terrorist entities in Syria'](https://www.rt.com/op-edge/361957-syria-white-helmets-un/)

[Syrian White Helmets a ‘terrorist support group & Western propaganda tool’](https://www.rt.com/op-edge/364105-aleppo-white-helmets-fraudulent/)

Is there any definitive evidence they were the heroes we have seen in the media? Or are they war propaganda?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Skeptics.SE and is not about governments,policies or political processes

Comment: @xrorox: Quite possibly both. Remember nobody operates in Idlibistan without Islamist rebel militia approval and coordination. No media, no international NGOs (or almost none; I might have missed sonething) - so you can only get the coverage they want you to get. And they don't operate anywhere in Syria - neither in regime-controlled areas nor in Rojava. So, what I'm saying is you can't know and there's evidence for both the legitimate and illegitimate aspects of their activity.

Comment: @OlivierPucher Don't forget that the US/UK media are also biaised. One example Sarin Gas at Ghouta. Many US/UK media were supportive of a military intervention against Assad. Now, even UN say the "rebels" were guilty. Don't be silly War propaganda exists on both sides. Governments have vested interests and are major sources for the press.   And these kinds of events : https://www.rt.com/news/386256-new-york-festivals-rt-awarded/  tend to prove that RT work is recognized as more that Putin's board.

Comment: @xrorox : thanks for the advice, I'll try not to be silly. I'm not sure it is the right place to discuss the quality of different media, but 1. No, UN doesn't accuse Syrian rebels of bombing Ghouta with Sarin Gas. 2. Beside avoiding possible bias, there are a lot of good practices that most serious media (not only western...) apply and RT doesn't even try to: diversity of sources, financial independance, publishing corrections when proven wrong, separation between articles (about facts) and tribunes (about opinions)...

Comment: @OlivierPucher It wasn't meant as an insult. More as a reminder that things are not black nor white.  My bad, the UN did not, it was UN officials that strongly suggest that it was the case : http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2013/may/6/syrian-rebels-used-sarin-nerve-gas-not-assads-regi/     Many serious medias are heavily subsidised by government. It is particulary true for french medias. And most of the journalists share same socials circles than politicians (still french medias).  Do you have a source about the failings of RT and sputnik (I'm actually interested in it) ?

Comment: @OlivierPucher They won many prizes in journalism outside of Russia. That's why I'm wondering.  Send them in PM, if possible. Otherwise, mods won't be happy with a discussion in the comments.

Comment: I'm desperately looking how to start a forum item or a private discusssion, but cannot find it. Your statement from C. Del Ponte is from 2013, a few days after the attack itself. A UN commission has been formed since, a lot of proof has been collected since about the Ghouta attack, and there is no doubt left (if there have ever been...) that the Syrian Army is the culprit.

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/mar/06/sarin-gas-attack-civilians-syria-government-un https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/mideast-crisis-syria-chemicalweapons/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66833/discussion-between-xrorox-and-olivier-pucher).

Comment: Actually, you are right. I just read their report.  In their conclusion, they concluded there was a chemichal attack at Ghouta. But they did not implicate anyone.  Report : https://unoda-web.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/report.pdf   Then you have the US claiming it's Assad. Others sources, sometimes study that claim they couldn't.   The only thing known is that mostly civilians and some Assad soldiers were targeted.

Comment: `Is there any definitive evidence they were the heroes we have seen in the media? Or are they war propaganda?` They are war propaganda, because they are pictured as the heroes in the media. This is the most definitive evidence one can imagine.

Comment: I think it's evident that they are propaganda, what's more interesting is if they help indiscriminately or if they mostly/only help a small group of people they are paid to help.

Answer (score 4):

The assertion that the White Helmets are linked to terrorists and propaganda materials would be propaganda according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Helmets_(Syrian_Civil_War)), citing:

- [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/syrian-rescue-organization-the-white-helmets-are-terrorists/), which rates it as unproven.
- [The Conversation](https://theconversation.com/who-are-syrias-white-helmets-and-why-are-they-so-controversial-66580), which dismisses it as the product of disinformation and spurious inference - citing [this TwitLonger](http://www.twitlonger.com/show/n_1solvrb).
- [Pulse](https://pulsemedia.org/2016/12/19/russia-and-the-syrian-regime-are-documenting-their-own-crimes/), which dismisses it as Russia and Syria documenting their own crimes.